# how to make wxpython grid automatic fit-to-window

Tags: python, user-interface, datagrid, wxpython

I am looking for a simple mode to to obtain automatic fit-to-window effect using a wx.grid.Grid object inside on of my window.

By now my 4 column grid has many white space on the right but I find this very ugly, better if all column expand or collapse based on window size change!

Is there a way to get this to works?

Comment: please provide a code and an image how your getting and how do you wan t to look .small example will solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL` function to expand your grid

```
myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
```

Edit -
In my experience, I had to add the sizer to the parent window, and also add the .Fit, or it wouldn't size until it was dragged.

```
myGrid = gridlib.Grid(mypanel)
BS = wx.BoxSizer()
BS.AddWindow(myGrid, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
mypanel.SetSizer(BS)    # this was important in my code
BS.Fit(mypanel)     # this may only be necessary to force first fit
```

Comment: In my experience, I had to add the sizer to the parent window, and also add the .Fit, or it wouldn't size until it was dragged.  Edited into post to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 6):

You need to catch the window resizing event and bind it to an event handler. I have shown it in this example:

```
import wx.grid

class Frame ( wx.Frame ):

        def __init__( self, parent ):
                wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Test", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 650,480 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

                self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
                sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
                self.panel = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
                self.inner_sizer = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
                self.grid = wx.grid.Grid( self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )

                # Grid
                self.grid.CreateGrid( 10, 4 )
                self.grid.EnableEditing( True )
                self.grid.EnableGridLines( True )
                self.grid.EnableDragGridSize( False )
                self.grid.SetMargins( 0, 0 )

                # Columns
                self.grid.EnableDragColMove( False )
                self.grid.EnableDragColSize( True )
                self.grid.SetColLabelSize( 30 )
                self.grid.SetColLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

                # Rows
                self.grid.EnableDragRowSize( True )
                self.grid.SetRowLabelSize( 80 )
                self.grid.SetRowLabelAlignment( wx.ALIGN_CENTRE, wx.ALIGN_CENTRE )

                # Label Appearance

                # Cell Defaults
                self.grid.SetDefaultCellAlignment( wx.ALIGN_LEFT, wx.ALIGN_TOP )
                self.inner_sizer.Add( self.grid, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


                self.panel.SetSizer( self.inner_sizer )
                self.panel.Layout()
                self.inner_sizer.Fit( self.panel )
                sizer.Add( self.panel, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 0 )

                self.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

                self.SetSizer( sizer )
                self.Layout()
                self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
                self.Show()

        def OnSize(self, event):
                width, height = self.GetClientSizeTuple()
                for col in range(4):
                        self.grid.SetColSize(col, width/(4 + 1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App()
        Frame(None)
        app.MainLoop()
```

If you have a variable number of columns simply put that variable in place of 4 in `OnSize`.